# Android shortcut intent with extra

Tags: android, shortcut

Is there any way to put an extra into the intent launched by a shortcut?

Comment: I don't think that it can be done. But why would you want that?

Comment: I want to give the user the ability to directly access different datasets of my app. To achieve this i have to know a identifier for each dataset. I wanted to store this identifier in the extra information of the intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating the shortcut, this works just fine. Just put the extras in the `Intent` that is what the shortcut should launch. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Introspection/QuickSender) demonstrating this.

Comment: I get null using your idea on android 4.4 and 6.1

Comment: @Choletski: Then I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, with a [mcve] demonstrating your problem and a complete explanation of your symptoms. Note that it is possible that individual home screen implementations may have problems here.